# render status when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a legacy Rails 2 project,

In my model class, I have a validation:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :foo, :scope => [:type, :gender], :message => "Already have such student"
 ...
end
```

It checks for uniqueness of field `foo` based on `type` and `gender` attributes, if a `student` with these attributes already exist while creating a new student, an error message is raise.

My question is, with this validation, instead of having that error message, how can I call `render :status => 422, :json=>"Already have such student"` ? Is it possible

==== controller ====

```
class StudentsController < BaseController

  def create
       student = Student.new({...})

       # Since there are other validations in Student class, it could be any reason student is nil here.
       if student.nil?
          render :status => :unprocessable_entity, :json => "Failed to create student."
       else
          render :status => :ok, :json=> student.to_json
       end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Please, show the controller code.

Comment: I put controller code there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

```
    class StudentsController < BaseController

      def create
        student = Student.new({...})

        if student.save
          render :status => :ok, :json=> student.to_json
        else
          render :status => :unprocessable_entity, :json => student.errors.full_messages
        end
      end 
    end
```

Actually student is never nil even if it is not valid. So your code will always render ok